# Store single value from each iteration for graphing

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration

I'm new to Matlab, trying to figure out how to store a single value from an iterative process that generates 1000 values per run.

```
[filename.m]

 x(1)=0;
 t(1)=0;
 dt=1;
 kB=1.381e-23;
 T=310;
 R=3.05e-9;
 visc=0.007;
 friction=6*pi*visc*R;
 D=kB*T/friction;
 dxdiff=(2*D*dt)^0.5;
 Force_applied=1e-15;
 for i=(2:1000)
     vx=Force_applied/friction;
     dx=vx*dt;
     x(i)=x(i-1)+dxdiff*randn+dx;
     t(i)=(i-1)*dt;
 end
```

So when I run this, it generates 1000 coordinates, but I only want to store the final value x(1000) for each iteration. So my ultimate question is what do I need to add to

```
for ii=1:1000
filename
end
```

in order to store each of the one thousand x(1000) values so that I can make a plot of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn `filename` into a function with an output, like so:

```
function output = filename() 
 x(1000)=0; %Preallocate x
 t(1000)=0; %Preallocate t
 dt=1;
 kB=1.381e-23;
 T=310;
 R=3.05e-9;
 visc=0.007;
 friction=6*pi*visc*R;
 D=kB*T/friction;
 dxdiff=(2*D*dt)^0.5;
 Force_applied=1e-15;
 for jj=(2:1000)
     vx=Force_applied/friction;
     dx=vx*dt;
     x(jj)=x(jj-1)+dxdiff*randn+dx;
     t(jj)=(jj-1)*dt;
 end
 output = x(1000); %Here we set the value of the output variable
```

Then you can call this function like

```
out(1000) = 0; %Preallocate out
for ii = 1:1000
out(ii) = filename();
end
```

Note that I've pre-allocated the arrays `x`, `t`, and `out` so that the code will be faster. You can read more about functions here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! I appreciate the resource as well.

Comment: The answer is correct for your question. Note that you do not need a loop in your function, you can simply use `x = cumsum( randn(999,1)*dxdiff + dx ) ;` instead of the loop, then return the last element of `x` as given in this answer.